# Have all the Torah we saw, even if we didn't learn it

Tags: sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy, olam-haba-world-to-come

Someone told me in Yeshiva that in the next life, whatever Torah we saw will be available to us, even if we didn't actually learn it. He was advising to flick through the whole of shas just in case.

Where did he get this idea from?

Comment: Consider the paradigm of “מחשבות זרות”. We learn that fixing words of Torah is accomplished minimally through the small action of moving our lips to form those words. It is preferable to actually pronounce. The Rabbe’im even had specific melodies for types of Torah, like recounted in HaYom Yom. But looking at words of Torah isn’t nothing, just like thinking without moving our lips isn’t. In navuah, one level is that the words we actually spoke are edited and repeated back to us. This emphasizes the importance of proper, distinct, unrushed pronunciation when learning and praying.

Comment: I heard from Reb Moshe Aharon Stern exactly the opposite. He said that since every part of the Torah is infinitely deep and the deeper you go the more interconnections there are between all parts of the Torah therefore even if you only learn one small part of the Torah since in *olam ha'bah* deeper and deeper aspects of that part of the Torah will be revealed to you this will result in your acquisition of the entire Torah. This is almost word for word the Ruach Chaim on the mishnah of *ha'lomed mechaveiroh perek achas*.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE What you are quoting is the distinction between שכר מצוה מצוה, and the statement of Rebbe in Avot 2:1 והוי זהיר במצוה קלה כבחמורה כו׳. This is discussed at great length in Chabad Chassidut & the current Rebbe specifically. But that is not what I was mentioning in my previous comment.

Comment: @User123 Precisely my point...

Comment: Who is "the current Rebbe" in Chabad? I thought the last one, who was not replaced, died 30 years ago?

Comment: @Imanonov we consider Rabbi Menachem Mendel Schneersohn to be the "Rebbe". When someone of Chabad talks about "The Rebbe", this does not refer to the Alter Rebbe, to the Maharash, but to the latest Rebbe of Chabad.

Comment: I vaguely remember hearing that Rav Nachum held that just saying the words suffices as the first steps ,never heard about just seeing